# Erase-Insert Idiom in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, malloc

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
auto it = vec.insert(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), vec.begin()+i);
vec.erase(it+i, vec.end());
```

But this gives a `malloc: corrupted top size` error:

```
vec.erase(vec.insert(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), vec.begin()+i)+i, vec.end());
```

Why is this happening and is there any way to fix this error?
The main question is, can I pass the results of insert() to erase() when both operate on the same vector?

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? Please add an example

Comment: the reason the erase-remove idom work is because `remove` does not actually remove elements from the container. `insert` on the other hand does insert elements into the container

Comment: This code makes my spider senses tingle, please don't...

Comment: The first may appear to work perfectly fine, but all `insert`'s arguments become invalid if it reallocates. You can't determine the absence of undefined behaviour by testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vec.end` can change due to the insert, after it's been evaluated as argument to `erase`. C++ does not guarantee that arguments are evaluated left-to-right.

There's no simple fix here. You need an iterator range for `erase`, but the `insert` changes the iterators of `vector`.

Comment: What do you mean by "reserving space"?

Comment: @NotAProgrammer: Good point, the end of course shifts by insertion, not just the base address.

Comment: @Bingwen: `vector.reserve` is a method which ensures that a vector has sufficient capacity to add new elements without moving the existing elements.

Comment: It might be worth adding that "**erase-remove**" is an idiom, "**erase-insert**" is not something that exists, let alone an idiom.

Comment: @MSalters what is the order of evaluation? If not left to right

Comment: @Bingwen: Arguments are fully evaluated before the function itself is called. Evaluation of one argument does not overlap with the evaluation of another argument, so there is _some_ order, but the order arg2, arg3, arg1 is perfectly valid.